# Set and call object instance in Python

Tags: python, oop

Not sure what I am doing wrong here when trying to initiate instance of object and set a name to the instance...

```
class Person:
    def Person(self, name):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

m = Person.Person('James')

m.name
```

Any help with an explanation?

I've personally not encountered a situation where the **init** function is nested beneath a parent function...

Comment: But what's happening? Are you asking about `TypeError: Person() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`?

Comment: read the [classes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I want the output to be: 'James'

Comment: This would work if `def Person` were `class Person`, that is you defined in _inner class_.  An `__init__` method inside a function is generally meaningless.

Comment: "I've personally not encountered a situation where the init function is nested beneath a parent function..." So why did you do it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is correlated to the function definition. Basically, you are calling Person function that define but doesn't call the **init** one. So, you can solve like that:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
m = Person('James')
m.name
```